# Lightning Tree CSS styling issue in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I want to increase the min-width of the slds-tree_container as the text gets wrapped beyond a certain width.

## Tree.html

```
  <template>
         <lightning-tree items={roleItems} class="" onselect={handleSelect} >
         </lightning-tree>
 </template>
```

[image]

Because of the new Shadow DOM styling in LWC I can't change the CCS style of the inner components (In this case slds-tree_container). Is there a way to set auto width ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally for a web component, this would work

```
const treeElement = this.template.querySelector("lightning-tree");
let style = document.createElement("style");
style.innerHTML = ".slds-tree_container { min-width: 800px; }";
treeElement.shadowRoot.appendChild(style);
```

> but because of lightning locker service accessing shadow dom is not
>   allowed(which is a good thing)
>   .

I would recommend extending the base component from here https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes/tree/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/tree and adding custom css as needed

Comment: Thanks. This method works. Although I have seen in few places discouraging to do so in LWC.